# Cos'è una "dora"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Al bar Moccia ci sarà qualcuno disposto a parlare di Pavese? Figurati chi pensa a Pavese, Pavese si è suicidato. A quest’ora, da Moccia, solo le vecchie golose che scelgono con cura le paste. Le chiamano coi dolci nomi affettuosi: scazzetta di cardinale, cassatina, sciù, preziosa, **dora**, cannolo e sfogliatella. E ne mangiano in piedi, compunte, almeno tre.

Non ho trovato la voce "dora" su nessun dizionario e ho curiosità di sapere cos'è. Ho ricercato anche su Google, ma non sono riuscita a individuare nessuna informazione su un dolce chiamato "dora". Qualcuno di voi ne saprebbe qualcosa?

Answer (score -1):

Ciao Charo,

prova a vedere qua:

https://www.originalitaly.it/it/store/s-dora-dessert

È tutto quello che sono riuscito a trovare; penso sia un dolce tipico della Campania ed in Italia dolci regionali ne abbiamo un'infinità, non puoi trovarli sui dizionari. Tanti hanno nomi anche dialettali.

Scusami se inserisco come risposta e non come commento ma il sistema mi dice che non ho un'adeguata reputazione per aggiungere un commento.

Comment: Lì si parla effettivamente di una torta “Dora”, ma la pasticceria che la fa si chiama “Do.Ra.” e quindi non è chiaro se il nome della torta è preesistente a quello della pasticceria...